# Objective-C – Profiling leaks shows Grand Central Dispatch is leaking

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch

Could someone please help me spot the leak. I don't really know where my leak is. So I will post my code here and hopefully someone can spot it for me. In the leaks instrument it says responsible frame is `dispatch_semaphore_create` which I'm not calling?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            if ([defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRunSeminars"]) {

                BOOL isUpdated = self.seminarsParser.seminarsAreUpdated;

                if (isUpdated) {
                    DLog(@"Seminars have been updated");

                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                     postNotificationName:@"updateSeminarsTable" 
                     object:nil];

                    [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:kSeminarsTabIndex] setBadgeValue:self.seminarsParser.numberOfNewSeminars];
                    self.seminarsParser.numberOfNewSeminars = nil;

                }
            }
        });

        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            if ([defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRunCareers"]) {

                BOOL isUpdated = self.careersParser.careersAreUpdated;

                if (isUpdated) {
                    DLog(@"Careers have been updated");

                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                     postNotificationName:@"updateCareersTable" 
                     object:nil];

                    [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:kCareersTabIndex] setBadgeValue:self.careersParser.numberOfNewCareers];
                    self.careersParser.numberOfNewCareers = nil;

                }
            }
        });

        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            if ([defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRunOffices"]) {

                BOOL isUpdated = [officesParser officesAreUpdated];

                if (isUpdated) {
                    DLog(@"Offices have been updated");

                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                     postNotificationName:@"updateOfficesTable" 
                     object:nil];
                }
            }
        });

        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you releasing the group after you're done with it, since you're creating a group within the outermost async block?  That's the only object I can see you creating which isn't being released properly.  Incidently, a group creates a semaphore behind the scenes (all a dispatch group really is, is some syntactic sugar around an internal dispatch semaphore), which is why instruments is reporting it that way.

Answer (score 3):

The zeroeth problem: What is being leaked?

Since I didn't see an obvious leak scanning your program, here's the most likely problem: UIKit objects are not threadsafe and only meant to be updated from the main thread, unless they enter your program from another thread.

Also note that `NSNotification`s are posted on the *calling* thread.

That means that all your UIKit type accesses and updates need to be performed on the main thread. And yes, that can introduce leaks or threading errors for which you should consider as undefined behaviour.

Comment: So since my notifications are essentially a call to a 'UITableView' to 'reloadData' I should put the "post notification" calls in  main threads?

Comment: @Peter Correct. If you want to see how your program flows in the debugger, add `assert([NSThread isMainThread]);` to all those methods that call directly or indirectly to UIKit objects (direct messages, property reads/writes, notifications, table reloads, etc.). In practice, you *can* message the UIKit objects to access *your* implementation/properties if you ensure your implementations are thread safe *and* if they do not enter the UIKit objects' implementation. Another common misconception is that `atomic_property == thread safe`, but it is not threadsafe.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same memory leaks (Malloc 64 bytes) after putting the call inside a main thread. The code that you see above is put inside `- applicationWillEnterForeground:` so each time I resume the application I get the memory leak. But when I come to think of it. It's not that posting notification that is causing the memory leak because I'm getting the leaks even if `isUpdated` is `NO`. What gives?

Comment: and that's after removing all the `dispatch_`/GCD calls?

Comment: You need to release the group after scheduling the completion callback.